# Unable to compile compass with any tools

Tags: ruby, compass-sass, prepros

i would to test tools to compile sass/compass instead of command line.
Actually i do it on my local LAMP server on virtual machine.So i upload files onto and it compile sass/compass.
But i develop on a windows 7 machine plugged on a windows server.
So source file sare on the server, i open them on my w7 pc, and upload them to my VM server.
It's not very easy and i'm looking for tools that can do this on my local w7 from source files.
So i did installed : Prepros , Scout and Koala.
All of them give me errors:

for Scout:

```
LoadError on line 1038 of org/jruby/RubyKernel.java: no such file to load -- susy
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb:161:in `require' X:\01_Drupal_ Ressources\02_Themes\04_Starter_PF\starter-susy-d6\config.rb:47:in `parse_string' org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1088:in `eval'
```

for Prepros,after setting using local ruby into advanced settings:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Prepros\ruby\bin\ruby.exe

Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Prepros/bin/gems.rb:17:in `<main>'

C:/Program Files (x86)/Prepros/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:264:in `bin_path': can't find gem compass ([">= 0"]) (
```

for Koala (setting local path to ruby = C:\Program Files (x86)\Koala\ruby\bin\ruby.exe):

```
\\Srv\doc_partage\Internet_et_Communication\04_Sites\01_Drupal_ Ressources\02_Themes\04_Starter_PF\starter-susy-d6\sass\application.scss
12:33:25
\\Srv\doc_partage\Internet_et_Communication\04_Sites\01_Drupal_ Ressources\02_Themes\04_Starter_PF\starter-susy-d6\sass\application.scss
'\\Srv\doc_partage\Internet_et_Communication\04_Sites\01_Drupal_ Ressources\02_Themes\04_Starter_PF\starter-susy-d6'
CMD.EXE a �t� d�marr� avec le chemin d'acc�s comme r�pertoire en
cours. Les chemins d'acc�s UNC ne sont pas prise en charge. Utilisation
du r�pertoire Windows par d�faut.
'compass' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme ex�cutable ou un fichier de commandes.
```

So the problem seem to be the same for all,but anything fix yet.
thanks for help.

Comment: with prepros : use th default ruby and get :
`LoadError on line ["45"] of C: cannot load such file -- susy
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
`
with koala,after updating cmd.exe, seem to be better but compass not found..`'compass' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme ex�cutable ou un fichier de commandes.`

Comment: install jruby,but no change , th ePath variable is C:\jruby-1.7.8\bin but i get : Unable to execute ruby —error spawn ENOENT  with prepros, no change with koala.Scout give me more hope : LoadError on line 1038 of org/jruby/RubyKernel.java: no such file to load -- susy ; see to install susy into jruby..